# Downsides to NOT calling UIViewController.addChild, .didMove, etc when embedding views from other view controllers

Tags: swiftui, uikit

What are the downsides to not following this process?

```swift
let parent = UIViewController()
let child = UIViewController()

parent.view.addSubview(child.view)
parent.addChild(child)
child.didMove(toParent: parent)

// and to remove
child.willMove(toParent: nil)
child.removeFromParent()
child.view.removeFromSuperview()
```

and instead just doing something more on the order of

```swift
let parent = UIViewController()
let child = UIViewController()

parent.view.addSubview(child.view)

// and to remove
child.view.removeFromSuperview()
```

My specific desire is to use SwiftUI views in place of `UIView`s sprinkled through my project, but *officially* you're supposed to use a `UIHostingController` and embed it as a child view controller of whatever parent view controller it belongs to.

I was previously under the impression that you **have** to call these methods, but then another developer suggested I just try not calling them with the assumption I'm only missing out on view controller lifecycle events (which I don't think matter to me in most cases). I've since tried it and it worked, but I'm worried about what I'm missing/why this might be a bad idea.

Comment: For SwiftUI case it is fine if you not calling them as we are mostly interested in the View part of that ViewController which will work. Otherwise, if you use them in some UIViewControllers stacks - you will miss lifecycle methods calls for the child view controller which can lead to some unexpected and hard to find issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently came across an example of something you might lose if you don't add the `UIHostingViewContoller` as a child of the parent view controller in this article about using SwiftUI views in self-sizing table view cells. If you don't add it as a child, the height of the cell holding its view is not always calculated correctly.

https://noahgilmore.com/blog/swiftui-self-sizing-cells/#view-controller-containment